# Python 3 can't decode certain characters when readin

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode

I have some super simple code trying to open a file, but it contains some Chinese/Arabic characters which I believe are stopping me from being able to open it. I'm not sure how to modify the file in order to allow it to open these characters. My code is simply

```
a_file = open("test2.txt")
lines = a_file.readlines()
print(lines)
```

and my error message is

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 2948: character maps to <undefined>
```

How do I fix this? Thanks!

Comment: Python is assuming that you want to have the file converted from bytes into a string using UTF-8 encoding.  The character 0x81 at position 2948 is illegal in that position.  When you open the file in a text editor, what do you see there?   What are you expecting Python to read?  You might want to try `open("test2.text",  encoding="ISO-8859-1")` which is a more lenient codec.

Comment: @FrankYellin that works, thanks! If you want to add a comment, I'll go ahead and accept your answer. Can you also elaborate on why that added part made it work? Thanks!

Comment: @FrankYellin using Latin-1 to decode Chinese or Arabic text is bad advice. The ISO-8859-1 encoding contains no Chinese or Arabic characters, except maybe for the ASCII digits `0`..`9`, which are often referred to as "Arabic numbers". Using Latin-1 to decode Arabic text "works" without an exception, but corrupts the input.

Comment: I agree with you.  But he did manage to read nearly 3000 characters.   My main piece of advice was to open the file and find out what it was reading.   And the advantage of ISO-8859-1 is that it can read pretty much anything; if your goal is just to move stuff without knowing what it is (and apparently original poster didn't), then it can be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 2948: character maps to

is telling you that the bytes in the file cannot be decoded using the system's default encoding (the "'charmap' codec can't decode" message typically appears on Windows systems using [legacy 8-bit encodings](https://tripleee.github.io/8bit/).)

If the file contains chinese or arabic characters it's more likely that the correct encoding to use when opening the file is UTF-8 or UTF-16.

Note that ISO-5589-1 / latin-1 encoding will decode any bytes, but the result may be meaningless, because it's an 8-bit encoding that can only represent 256 characters.

```py
>>> s = '你好，世界'
>>> bs = s.encode('utf-8')
>>> print(bs.decode('ISO-8859-1'))
ä½ å¥½ï¼ä¸ç
```